# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED exclusively in browsers

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, browser, connection

I was working on a website on my local computer (mac OS High Sierra) and had put some redirects in the websites `.htaccess` file (in order to get images from the remote server instead of downloading them). After this it seemed that I could no longer access the website from my Chrome browser. Chrome would answer to any URL leading to the remote server with `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`.

I tried other browsers on my computer such as Firefox, Chrome Canary, Chromium and Opera. None of them could provide a connection.

Next I checked with a different internet access via TOR-Browser on the same computer whether I could access the website, and it worked.

Next I checked via Terminal whether I could connect to the remote server with `ping`, `nslookup` and `traceroute`. All connecting to the server as expected.

I googled up possible solutions to this problem but could not find one so far. I had read that resetting the DNS cache could help and tried `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder` but it did not.

I did not edit the `/etc/hosts` file; a restart of the computer did not help; a reset of the `.htaccess` to the previous state did not help; resetting the caches in the browsers did not help.

How can I access the remote website from my browsers normally again?

EDIT1: Related question: [Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED for only selective images from instagram API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941476/failed-to-load-resource-neterr-connection-refused-for-only-selective-images-f)

EDIT2: After about one day I was able to access the remote website again with no further incidents of `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` even after putting the redirects into the `.htaccess` file. So it seems to me of being some sort of caching on my computer which prevents the browsers from accessing the remote website. However I have no clue what caused the error message in the first place and what kind of cache it might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after EDIT2 when I was able to access the remote website again, the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` appeared again - this time I tested another device with the same internet connection and I had encountered the connection error too. Now I believe it has something to do with the router and/or it's firewall - not the ISP since I could connect to the remote website with shell commands (named above). The image requests to the remote website seem to cause the router to block further access from browsers, probably as a security measure similar to the situation in this article https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/can-t-access-a-specific-website-going-thru-my-router-274637/

Comment: FYI,the link in your answer doesn't work now.